# Apache2: Hosting Multiple Sites (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, apache-httpd, hosts, systemctl

I am new working with system.d and services on ubuntu/debian. I'm trying to serve multiple sites on the same **Apache2** (I am note sure if I should have 3 apache2 folders for the each service). The configuration layout of the installation looks as follows:

[image: the configuration layout of the installation looks as follows]

I need to configure three instances of server to listen on ports 8081, 8082, and 8083 respectively. For example, on visiting http://host1.com:8081, http://host2.com:8082 and http://host3.com:8083 the HTML pages are in var /var/mysites/host1/index.html, /var/mysites/host2/index.html and /var/mysites/host3/index.html respectively should be rendered by default. Also, we should be able to start, to stop and restart the apache server using the following commands:

```
sudo apache2ctl-host1 start; sudo apache2ctl-host2 start; sudo apache2ctl-host1 start;
sudo apache2ctl-host1 stop; sudo apache2ctl-host2 stop; sudo apache2ctl-host1 stop;
sudo apache2ctl-host1 restart; sudo apache2ctl-host2 restart; sudo apache2ctl-host1 restart;
```

To test my instances, it was required these conditions:

The Apache2 webserver installation is verified by running the `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache2` command.

The server instances are started by running sudo `apachec2ctl-host1 start; sudo apachec2ctl-host2 start; sudo apachec2ctl-host3 start;`

The port is verified by running the sudo `lsof -i:8081 | grep apache2, sudo lsof -i:8082 | grep apache2and sudo lsof -i:8083 | grep apache2` commands.

Th HTML conted is fetched by running the
`curl host1.com:8081`,
`curl host2.com:8082` and
`curl host3.com:8083` commands.

The page must not be a 403 or 404 error page, ie., the following commands must exit with non-zero code:

```
curl host1.com:8081 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8082 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8083 | grep 403\ Forbidden
curl host1.com:8081 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
curl host1.com:8082 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
curl host3.com:8083 | grep 404\ Not \ Found
```

Also, the HTML files
`/var/save/mysites/host1/index.html`,
`/var/save/mysites/host2/index.html` and
`/var/save/mysites/host3/index.html` and the rendered HTML files should be exactly same.

My real question is, how do I create a service like this example?

```
sudo apache2ctl-host1 start
```

Comment: You do not need 3 separate apache installations. Did you already tell `apache2` to use those ports? What you are trying to achieve is probably done easier by using multiple site configurations. Search "apache virtualhost"

Comment: What is the purpose of running a separate apache setup for each port? One apache instance can listen on all required ports. Which vhosts are available on which ports is decided by the setup of each vhost. Absent any compelling reason, my answer to your question, "how do I create a service like this?" is "don't, there is no need"

Comment: If you really want to use 3 (or 4?) separate instances, read `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.multiple-instances`.

Comment: @grifferz thanks for your comment! I already did the "standard" way. But I wanted to learn how create a service to run, stop, or restart my own service for each html page separately

Comment: @Panki thanks for answer my question! I already know how to use multiple hosts in the standard way. I would like to do it differently, I know I may not need it, but I would like to learn how to use my own service to stop or restart apache for a specific html page.

Comment: Thing is this isn't a research site. If you want to learn about instanced systemd services I suggest reading the systemd documentation with a goal in mind that it actually makes sense for. The answer to how to disable individual apache vhosts is: ```$ sudo a2dissite sitename-to-disable && sudo apache2ctl graceful```